# Proper attribution of 'BSD 3-Clause License' code in a MIT license project

Tags: licensing, mit, license-compatibility, github, bsd

I have a repository on Github that I want to license under the MIT license. I have copy pasted parts of two other projects, one which is under an MIT license, and another which is under a BSD 3-Clause License. This is how my license file looks like right now:

```
* This repository as a whole is under the following MIT license:

// ... my MIT license

* Parts of this project was derived from [Project A](https://github.com/projecta) 
and so the license from it's repository is included below:

// ... Project A's BSD 3-Clause License

* Parts of this project was derived from [Project B](https://github.com/projectB) 
and so the license from it's repository is included below:

// ... Project B's MIT license
```

Is this proper attribution of the other projects?

Is licensing my project under MIT when I used part of a project with a BSD 3-Clause License okay?

If I incorporated more projects, would I have to do the above for each one? That would make my LICENSE very long...

Comment: Does [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9595/458) deal with your last point?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes, it does. I do have to do it for each one. Thanks

Comment: No worries - glad you got an answer!

Comment: What about the second point: 'Is licensing my project under MIT when I used part of a project with a BSD 3-Clause License okay?'

Comment: I'm so sorry, I closed the question prematurely; I have rectified this error.  That said, you might also want to take a look at [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/7673/458), because it applies equally to using MIT code derivatives under BSD.

Comment: Oh, ok, so if I understand correctly, the answer to all three of my questions is 'yes'?

Comment: I think so, yes.  Do you want me to write up a short answer saying that, or are you happy with the duplicates?

Comment: You can close it. Thanks